# Why laravel 4.1 is giving class does not exist error for a namespaced class?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having an issue in laravel 4.1. I'm following a tutorial series. I have "Acme/Transformers" folder in "app" directory which has two class "Transformer.php" and "LessonTransformer.php". When i tried to access "LessonTransformer.php" in LessonController class of Controller directory i'm getting the following issue.

```
ReflectionException
Class Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer does not exist
```

I updated my composer.json file like following.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/Acme"
    ],
    "psr-0":{
        "Acme" : "app/Acme"
    }
```

and ran

```
"composer dump-autoload -o"
```

but it made no change in the output. I have no ideas what's going on. Please help me.

Here's is my LessonsController.php class

```
use Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer;

class LessonsController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * @var Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer
     */
     protected $lessonTransformer;

     function __construct(LessonTransformer $lessonTransformer){
         $this->lessonTransformer = $lessonTransformer;
     }

     /**
      * Display a listing of the resource.
      *
      * @return Response
      */
     public function index()
     {
         $lessons = Lesson::all();
         return Response::json([
             'lessons' => $this->lessonTransformer->transformCollection($lessons->toArray())
         ], 200);
     }

     /**
      * Display the specified resource.
      *
      * @param  int  $id
      * @return Response
      */
     public function show($id)
     {
          $lesson = Lesson::find($id);

          if(!$lesson){
               return Response::json([
                        'error' => [
                            'mesage' => 'Lessons does not exits'
                        ]
               ], 404);
          }

          return Response::json([
               'lesson' => $this->lessonTransformer->transform($lesson)
          ], 200);
      }

      /**
       * Map over the lesson collection and cast it in an array,
       * so that we can map over it.
       *
       * Transform a collection of lesson
       * 
       * @param  array $lessons
       * @return array
       */
      public function transformCollection(array $lessons){
          return array_map([$this,'transform'], $lessons);
      }

      /**
       * Transform a single object(lesson)
       * Instead of returning everything, we return some selected data.
       * We replaced the keys that exposed the DB structure with some
       * other keys because if we wish to change the keys of data in 
       * future then we can change it without affecting the DB structure.
       * 
       * @param  array $lesson
       * @return array
       */
      public function transform($lesson){
          return [
                'title'     => $lesson['title'],
                'body'      => $lesson['body'],
                'active'    => (boolean)$lesson['some_bool']
          ];
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the

```
namespace Acme\Transformers;
```

line at the top of the `LessonTransformer.php` file?
Also check for plurality of the filenames. Often mistakes come from a file named `LessonTransformer.php` and the class named `LessonsFormatter` (mind the `s`).

**EDIT**

These should be the top lines of your files:

app/src/Acme/Transformers/Transformer.php

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Transformers;

class Transformer
{
```

app/src/Acme/Transformers/LessonTransformer.php

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Transformers;

class LessonTransformer extends Transformer
{
```

app/controllers/LessonsController.php

```
<?php

use Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer;

class LessonsController extends BaseController
{
```

Comment: I have "namespace Acme\Transformers\Transformer" line at the top of the LessonTransformer.php because using "namespace Acme\Transformers" gave "Class 'Transformer' not found" error.

I also checked for plurality of the filenames. File name and class name matches.

Comment: Well... There's your problem. The namespace should be `Acme\Transformers`. Then look for a problem in the `Acme\Transformers\Transformer.php` file.

Comment: i also tried with "Acme\Transformers" but got "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
Class 'Transformer' not found" error

Comment: hannesvdvreken "Class 'Transformer not found" issue is solved after i removed the "psr-0" part from autoload in composer.json and ran "composer dump-autoload". But i'm still gettting "ReflectionException
Class Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer does not exist" error.

Comment: If it says: `Class Transformer not found` then you're trying to load class Transformer from the root namespace. Try to look for a missing `use` statement in the controller or LessonTransformer. Also: put back the psr-0, it is absolutely necessary. Further: watch the EDIT on my answer. Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. After observing your edited answer, i noticed that i was using "use Acme\Transformers" instead of "namespace Ace\Transformers" in the "LessonTransformer.php". This silly mistake took my whole day. Thank you once again. :)

Comment: You're very welcome! If you could tag my answer as right then I'd be very happy.

Answer (score 3):

maybe you forget to update your composer.json: add app/Acme to classmap

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/Acme"
    ]
},
```

and run `composer dump-autoload`on your terminal